# C++ move constructor with IBM Rhapsody

Tags: c++, rhapsody

I am running IBM Rhapsody 8.1.5 here and moving a code base to modern C++.

I now face the issue that I can't define a move constructor, if a copy constructor is already defined, because Rhapsody simply ignores lvalue and rvalue references and thinks both constructors are the same.

Since I can't even choose the move constructor during creation, I tried to add && manually. Which also works, but Rhapsody won't let me save, because it thinks the Operation is a duplicate.

Does anybody have an idea how to achieve this in Rhapsody? Is this even possible, maybe at least with a more recent version? I would be happy to supply more information, if anything more helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is IMHO a bug in the product.
These workarounds exist in version 8.4:

- First create a constructor of your class A with argument type int (or any other type different from A), then go to **Features...** → **Arguments** and change the argument type to A and the code pattern to $type&&
- Use **C++ Declaration** A&& instead of **existing type** for the argument